# How to slide toggle a div right to left?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, width, slidetoggle

Please see this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MKwwH/

I want the link `images-link` to slide toggle right to left?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hidden').hide()
});

$('.soundDiv-link').click(function() {
  $('#soundDiv').slideToggle("slow")
});

$('.videoDiv-link').click(function() {
  $('#videoDiv').next().animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});

$('.imagesDiv-link').click(function() {
  $('#imagesDiv').animate({width: 'toggle'}, "slow")
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you have left and right set.  Just set right to 0 and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/MKwwH/4/

```
#imagesDiv {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You where almost right :

```
$('#videoDiv').next().animate({width: '100%'}, "slow");
```

But first you need to put width to a 0px;

See this working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfpks/).

Comment: Thanks but this wasn't quite what I needed. I wanted it to look like it is sliding out for the right side of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

USE THIS FOR RIGHT TO LEFT SLIDING :

```
<div class="nav ">
       <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
       </ul>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav{
    position: fixed;
    right:0;
    top: 70px;
    width: 250px;
    height: calc(100vh - 70px);
    background-color: #333;
    transform: translateX(100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

}
.nav-view{
    transform: translateX(0);
}
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a#click-a').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass('nav-view');
  });
});
```

SOURCE FILES: [WATCH TUTORIAL AND DOWNLOAD SOURCE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NBFO4xfVFVU&feature=youtu.be&t=1)