# How to slide a div out

Tags: jquery, css

I want to slide out a div from a certain position on the page. When the user hovers over the label with "View Status" in the table in the image below I want a div to appear as if it is sliding out to the left of that box in the table - the sliding div has to be on top of the table.

I'm currently using CSS/jQuery to make it slide down from where it is positioned in the code, but I don't know how to change where it is positioned on the page (or how to make it slide to the left rather than down).

```
<div id="flyoutDiv" class="hidden flyout">Some contents of the div</div>

.hidden { display: none; }

.flyout {
width: 560px;
height: 56px;
background-color: #EFF7DF;
padding: 10px;
border-radius: 10px;
border: solid 1px #CC6600;
position: abosolute;
overflow: hidden;
z-index: 10000;
    top: 100px;
    right: 300px; }
```

/* I added the top and right properties as part of the solution */

```
$('.lblViewStatus').hover(function() {
    $('.flyout').slideToggle();
});
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

I found [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rfUWg/) that functions the way I want it to (I can work with sliding down). I have nearly the same code, so I don't know why mine is continuously sliding up and down when the mouse stays on the label.

**jsFiddle**
I added [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eventide/5c25r/). A very basic example of my set up. Feel free to work with that.

**WORKING**

The reason it was constantly sliding in and out was because the div was sliding over where my mouse was, which triggered the toggle. I fixed that by changing the "right" property on the div.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19316805/how-to-slide-toggle-a-div-right-to-left

Comment: A good article that shows sliding from all directions is here: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
$('.lblViewStatus').hover(function() {
  $('.flyout').toggle("slide", {direction:'left'});
});
```

Comment: This almost works, but as the mouse is hovered over the label (lblViewStatus) the div continually slides in and out.

Comment: change this `.lblViewStatus` to your label id.

Comment: I can't. This is in a table and each row will have that same label in it to instruct the user to hover over the text to view the status.

Comment: try change as below, and I not tested yet. cause I don't have you source
`$('.lblViewStatus').hover(function(this) {
      $('.flyout').toggle("slide", {direction:'left'});
    });`

Comment: JS error on "this" in "(function(this)". I tried making it a jQuery object "(function($(this))", but that didn't work either.